# Why was "Why does the vim-jedi popup have weird line wrapping" closed?

Tags: discussion, closed-questions

This question was closed earlier today: [Why does the vim-jedi popup have weird line wrapping?](https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/3794/51)

The given reason was:

> This question was caused by a problem that can **no longer be reproduced** or a **simple typographical error**. While similar questions may be on-topic here, this one was resolved in a manner unlikely to help future readers.

However:

- It doesn't seem to be a "simple typographical error".
- It looks like the author is still having the problem, so "no longer be reproduced" also doesn't seem applicable.

Also note that it says (emphasis mine): **"this one was resolved** in a manner [..]". This is not a resolved question.

As I see it, this close reason is intended for typos, other simple "oopsies", and mysterious problems that magically fix themselves and cannot be reproduced by anyone else.

I have re-opened it for now...

Comment: I think the votes were motivated by the "can no longer be reproduced" part: It seems that the error occurred only with the OP configuration and no one reported having this problem (or reproducing it) although the question were asked several months ago. I don't know if it's a good enough reason to close the post but I think that's what explain the votes.